# Handlings Blanks in Yes/No columns

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have an excel file with one column that has either Yes/No or Blanks.  When I import this into Access, the column data type is automatically set to Yes/No.  When I open the table it mirrors what was in the excel file, which is fine, example below:

**Tasked**
Yes

No
No

When I use this table as part of make-table build – that includes several outer joins – the Tasked column reads -1/0 instead.  The problem with this is that the blanks are set to 0, so I can't tell what job has yet to be Tasked.

I understand you can't have blanks in Yes/No column in Access, but in reality this doesn't help.
I have read several forums with advice on this but nothing is working?

Comment: Please post some sample data and a small make-table query that reproduces the issue. Be aware that in Access, `Yes/No` fields are not nullable so they cannot be "blank", they must either be `Yes` or `No`. Be sure to tell us the field type of the source column (Text?, Number?, ...?).

Comment: I've edited my original question, but the query itself is quite complex so don't know how best to upload it?  Hopefully the above should help.

Comment: I just tried importing a table from Excel into a new table in Access and my [Tasked] field was imported as `Text`, not `Yes/No`. Then I tried another import to force the [Tasked] field to `Yes/No` but the values were not imported, presumably because Access was expecting `-1` for Yes and `0` for No. Are you **sure** that the [Tasked] field in your imported table is `Yes/No`?

Comment: The excel file is a dump from another access database.  The Tasked field just has True or False in it, so when I import it, Access is changing the data type to Yes/No.